# Executar arquivo Python com argumentos

Tags: python, batch, argumento

No meu programa, eu faço a seguinte operação:

```
import sys
qtd_ponts = int(sys.argv[1])
```

Eu gostaria de saber uma maneira prática de rodar esse arquivo **.py** passando argumentos sem precisar de uma IDE, usando arquivos **.bat** por exemplo.

Comment: No seu arquivo bat, basta colocar python arquivo.py [arg1 arg2 ...], não?

Comment: sim! funcionou! Nao imaginei que fosse tão simples. Coloque como resposta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para executar um script como bat ou diretamente do console, basta colocar o seguinte comando:

```
python arquivo.py [arg1 arg2 ...]
```

Lembrando que, no caso do Windows, a pasta em que o python está instalado precisa estar na variável de ambiente (path).

Comment: Felipão! sabe tudo de python :)

Comment: Longe disso, ainda tem muito o que aprender. (: